# Is it possible avoid specific trace (nodes) in internet?

Tags: internet, ping, internet-connection, traceroute

Is it possible avoid an internet node using the router, or a directive in the firewall? This is not because privacy, it's because I can't join a server due to a heavy saturated node.

Comment: Did you edit the comment? Cos I swear I just read someone totally different

Comment: How do you know that a saturated node is the reason? Maybe you could just use a different server.

Comment: Ok let me give some details.. All South America is playing battlefield on Brasilian servers founding everyone the same problem: the ping is so high that you would play better on china, Europe, etc. Somebody share a snapshot about a command that I don't remember right now, but all nodes until the target are shown, some with 5ms, others with 18ms to respond but one or two are taking so long.. more that 200ms.. so if you plus all of them you get why you're getting 1000 or 1200 ping. I just ask if there is a way to avoid that servers, providers or whatever.

Comment: @Ramhound No, that is not true at all... All the DNS server does is resolve a name to an IP address, how that destination IP address is routed is purely at the whim of the carrier who is controlling the packet at that moment. A DNS server MIGHT give a different IP address resolution to the DNS record request, but how the packet is routed has nothing to do with the DNS server or the information received from it.

Comment: @acejavelin I disagree. Had a problem with a program which couldn't communicate with an address.  When I used a different DNS provider I was able to communicate with it.  But I concede I over simplified my statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Is it possible avoid specific trace (nodes) in internet?"

Although your question is vague, I assume you basically want to know if your can control a packet of data's route through the Internet from end to end... Meaning you want to be able to say "use router A instead of router B" or "next hop is B instead of A" somewhere along the path that packet traverses.

Unless you are the ISP and have full control of that packet from cradle to grave, the answer is no. You can only control the path that packet of data would take from where it either ingresses into your network or is originated within your network, until it egresses out of your network.

After that occurs, the routing of the data packet will vary based on the routing rules of the carrier handling the packet at that time, which could be just your ISP, or they could hand it off to an upstream carrier who could in turn pass it off to any number of other carriers with any number of possible paths before it reaches it's destination.

In fact, this very page you are looking at may not, and probably did not, have all it's data packets transpose the exact same path top get to you... One packet can go one way, another packet a different route, a third packet another route, etc. from the hosting server to your web browser which puts the packets back together and in order. These packets could have taken COMPLETELY different routes to get to you, even completely different directions around the world.

Also be aware that traceroute/tracert, although a good tool for troubleshooting and diagnostics, does not always show the "big picture" and an issue could appear in a traceroute at "Hop 6" does not mean there is REALLY a problem there, it could just be prioritizing a ping return lower than actually routing data, for one example.

So to answer your question, no, you as a normal user cannot tell a packet of data to avoid a specific route or node on the Internet.

Comment: Wow wonderful answer. Thank you very much. I'm not sure if I'm able to vote as the solution but in fact it's perfect answer. I'll vote if I can. Thank you